# How to query and space address with multiple values when some are NULL

Tags: sql, string, oracle

I'm trying to query and correctly format an address made up of multiple values in Oracle when some of those values are NULL. Coalesce() works well for this but not when I add spacing/punctuation.

Examples

```
address 1: 123 Main St
address 2: Apt 1
City: New York
State: NY
Postal Code: 10001
Country: USA

address 1: NULL
address 2: NULL
City: New York
State: NULL
Postal Code: 10001
Country: USA
```

When pulling in the full address, I'm wanting to ignore the subsequent punctuation if a value is NULL so there aren't excess commas/spaces.

```
select a.address1 || ' ' || a.address2 || ', ' || a.city || ', ' || a.state || ' ' || a.postal_code || ', ' || 'USA',
Coalesce(a.address1, a.address2, a.city, a.state, a.postal_code,'USA') 
from address a
```

- Example 1 Result: 123 Main St Apt 1, New York, NY 10001, USA
- Example 2 Result: , New York,  10001, USA

Desired Result for example 2: New York, 10001, USA

This is just one example but I'm wanting a still properly formatted line when any combination of the elements are missing.

Comment: Just feed the address you build to regexp_replace, like this: `Regexp_replace(youradress, '^[ ,]+|[ ,]+$|, ?(?>,)') `.  This post-processes what you build looking for, and removing, all funny-looking punctuation.  It's a little subtle, using a lookahead in the middle section to remove multiple commas but retain at least one.

Comment: @ChrisMaurer - Oracle regex doesn't support lookaheads, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could us [the `nvl2()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/NVL2.html) to append the comma and space to each column value, only if it is not null, and then just concatenate those together:

```
select nvl2(address1, address1 || ', ', null)
  || nvl2(address2, address2 || ', ', null)
  || nvl2(city, city || ', ', null)
  || nvl2(state, state || ', ', null)
  || nvl2(postal_code, postal_code || ', ', null)
  || 'USA' as address
from address
```

| ADDRESS |
| --- |
| 123 Main St, Apt 1, New York, NY, 10001, USA |
| New York, 10001, USA |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/pOw7oFS0)

If you weren't adding the fixed 'USA' at the end then you could end up with a trailing comma, which you could trim off.

---

... except I just noticed you don't want a comma between `address1` and `address2`... you can handle that with a nested `nvl2()`:

```
select nvl2(address1, address1 || nvl2(address2, ' ', ', '), null)
  || nvl2(address2, address2 || ', ', null)
  || nvl2(city, city || ', ', null)
  || nvl2(state, state || ', ', null)
  || nvl2(postal_code, postal_code || ', ', null)
  || 'USA' as address
from address
```

| ADDRESS |
| --- |
| 123 Main St Apt 1, New York, NY, 10001, USA |
| 123 Main St, New York, NY, 10001, USA |
| Apt 1, New York, NY, 10001, USA |
| New York, 10001, USA |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/dRzpKH-1) (with added rows with just `address1` or `address2`, as well as both/neither, for the output shown above).

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE('Just concat without worrying about NULL','( ,)+', '')
```